# R's randomForest() function error - any way I can get more info?

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm getting the error message that "Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data."

This confuses me, since I am able to get the same dat sets working under rpart and ctree.  These functions conveniently enough report which factors are causing the bug, so it's easy to debug.  Right now I'm not sure which factors in my many dimensions are causing problems.

Is there a simple way to know which columns/variables are throwing randomForest off?

For what it's worth:

```
> write.csv(predict(object=train_comp.rp, newdata = test_w_age, type = c("prob")), file="test_predict_rp_w_age.csv")
> write.csv(predict(object=train_comp.rf, newdata = test_w_age, type = c("prob")), file="test_predict_rf_w_age.csv")
Error in predict.randomForest(object = train_comp.rf, newdata = test_w_age,  : Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data.
```

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example?

Comment: You might consider using examples from the package help page if you are unable to post your own data as an example.

Comment: General remark: to show type of variables in data.frame use `sapply(df, class)`. You can apply this for training and prediction sets and compare results to find the differences.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get around randomForest Error in R (Predictors in new data do not match)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033763/how-to-get-around-randomforest-error-in-r-predictors-in-new-data-do-not-match)