# How to get around randomForest Error in R (Predictors in new data do not match)

Tags: r, random-forest

I am having a hard time troubleshooting the error message below. I am trying to do a random forest model on a `titanic` data set. Is there a way to get around this error? Is there a code to check the levels in the tree?

```
Error in predict.randomForest(my_rf_model, test1) : Type of predictors in new data
    do not match that of the training data.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably occurring because one of the predictor variables in `test1` is a factor variable that has a value not present in the original data set. For example, if `titanic` has a column called `group` that can have values `A` or `B`, but `test1$group` can have a value of `C`, then you would get that error.

For example:

```
data(iris)
iris$group = factor(sample(c("A","B"), nrow(iris), replace=TRUE))
rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris)

newdat = iris
newdat$group = "C"

predict(rf, newdata=newdat)
```

> Error in predict.randomForest(rf, newdata = newdat) :    Type of
>   predictors in new data do not match that of the training data.

Comment: Or if the levels are different between the training and test sets.  Say if `titanic$group` had levels "A" and "B" but `test1$group` was a factor with only level "A".  That is, in addition to extra levels causing this, it could also be missing levels.